# Bootstrap 4 - card overflow in small screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

in my application, I use a lot the bootcard .card class.

Only, very often when I switch to mobile view, I notice a big overflow, which causes a display bug, and my whole page is found shifted.

Which means that I have to change the code in my .card class each time to make sure everything fits even in mobile view. It's very weird

**On large screen :**

[image]

**On small screen :**

[image]

This is the code :

```
<div class="card mt-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">
        Abonnement
        <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-1">Ne pas résilier l'abonnement</button>
        </div>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PRODUIT</th>
                    <th>PROCHAINE FACTURE</th>
                    <th>CRÉÉ LE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        TETETE
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary">Annulation prévue 03/05/2020</span>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-secondary">
                            basic
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Pas de prochaine facture
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        03/04/2020
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it possible replace the table with columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card mt-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">
      Abonnement
      <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-1 float-sm-right">Ne pas résilier l'abonnement</button>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <h5>PRODUIT</h5>
          TETETE
          <span class="badge badge-secondary">Annulation prévue 03/05/2020</span>
          <p class="text-secondary">
            basic
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <h5>PROCHAINE FACTURE</h5>
          <p class="text-secondary">
            Pas de prochaine facture
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <h5>CRÉÉ LE</h5>
          <p class="text-secondary">
            03/04/2020
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also a valid solution

Answer (score 2):

Add class `table-responsive` to the `table`:

```css
body{ width: 360px; } /* Galaxy S */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mt-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">
        Abonnement
        <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-1">Ne pas résilier l'abonnement</button>
        </div>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PRODUIT</th>
                    <th>PROCHAINE FACTURE</th>
                    <th>CRÉÉ LE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        TETETE
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary">Annulation prévue 03/05/2020</span>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-secondary">
                            basic
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Pas de prochaine facture
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        03/04/2020
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but it's a solution that I had already considered, but I don't like having to put my table in responsive, because it forces me to scroll to see the rest of the table when there is not much thing.

Is there no other way to get everything in?

Comment: Other option would be to reduce the font-size to too small, but this is a standard implementation of viewing tables on mobile devices. It is why the table-responsive class exists